# Convert JSON date list to python date format

Tags: python, date

I've got this list of birthdate that is in JSON format, that I want to convert to Python format. What would be the easiest way to convert to python date format?

```
print(birthdate_json[:5])
```

gives me the following results :

```
['/Date(1013230800000)/', '/Date(1016600400000)/', '/Date(1010466000000)/', '/Date(1017205200000)/', '/Date(1020052800000)/']
```

While I would the desired input to be :

```
'2002-02-09', '2002-03-20', '2002-01-08', '2002-03-27', '2002-04-29'
```

Comment: JSON seems to be irrelevant to the question; you just have a Python `list` containing strings that appear to be some custom date format. (The integer in each string appears to be the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.)

Comment: In other words, focus on your actual problem. If you were given **a string** `'/Date(1013230800000)/'`, parse _that_. Loop _that function_ over your list

Comment: You could extract the UNIX timestamp through list comprehensions and convert them using something like `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(<UNIXtimestamp>).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: That's not a "python date format".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetime.fromtimestamp()` in `datetime` module to convert epochtime to datetime, as follows:

```py
from datetime import datetime

birthdate_json = [
    '/Date(1013230800000)/',
    '/Date(1016600400000)/',
    '/Date(1010466000000)/',
    '/Date(1017205200000)/',
    '/Date(1020052800000)/'
]
birthdate = []
for i in range(len(birthdate_json)):
    epoch_time = int(birthdate_json[i][6:-2])/1000
    datetime_type_value = datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch_time)
    # uncomment next line If you want str value of datetime such as ["2022-02-23", "2022-02-24" ...]
    # datetime_type_value = datetime_type_value.strftime("%F")
    birthdate.append(datetime_type_value)

print(birthdate)

# datetime type values will be printed:
# [datetime.datetime(2002, 2, 9, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2002, 3, 20, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2002, 1, 8, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2002, 3, 27, 14, 0), datetime.datetime(2002, 4, 29, 13, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the approaches to solve your problem is to use a list comprehension such as:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import re
# Your code to extract data from JSON file and assign them to `birthdate_json` variable
[datetime.fromtimestamp(float((re.search("Date\((.+)\)",x).group(1)))/1000).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for x in birthdate_json]
```

which regarding the example of `birthdate_json[:5]` would result in:

```
['2002-02-09', '2002-03-20', '2002-01-08', '2002-03-27', '2002-04-29']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use pd.to_datetime like this:

```
df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

These times are in epoch milliseconds. You can convert them to a `datetime` object:

```py
import datetime

x = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1013230800000")/1000)
print(x.strftime("%F"))
```

```py
>>> 2002-02-09
```